# Dataset of RaggedTensors - "arguments do not form a valid RaggedTensor"

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to create a tf.data.Dataset of RaggedTensors in the following snippet:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 100, output_type=tf.int32)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.concat([tf.zeros(1, dtype=tf.int32), tf.fill([x], x)], axis=0))
dataset
dataset = dataset.map(
    lambda x: tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_splits(values=x, row_splits=[0, 1]))

for i in dataset.take(3):
  print(i)
```

But I'm seeing the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_1_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} assertion failed: [Arguments to _from_row_partition do not form a valid RaggedTensor] [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:] [x (RaggedFromRowSplits/strided_slice_1:0) = ] [1] [y (RaggedFromRowSplits/strided_slice:0) = ] [2]
     [[{{function_node RaggedFromRowSplits_assert_equal_1_Assert_AssertGuard_false_3238}}{{node RaggedFromRowSplits/assert_equal_1/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext] name:
```

I'm confused about why it's complaining about x != y when that's the point of RaggedTensors.